# Detecting collisions without (very small) interfering with physical objects?

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I would like to take advantage of the collision msgs by checking if some objects pass trough a given area.
I would create the area as an invisible link, with a collision that actually does not interfere with the other objects, but still knows when it collides with them. Is it possible to set up the parameters in such a way?
I could set the thickness of the object really small and the penetration depth larger, would that do it? Or it will skip collision detection?

I did not have the time to test this yet, I just wanted to know in advance if it is possible, so I will know where to start.

@hsu?

I will give an update in a while after trying this.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5736/detecting-collisions-without-(very-small)-interfering-with-physical-objects?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-03-26**:
I have a branch (collision_bitmask) started that will do what you are asking for. Let me look at it tomorrow to see where it stands.

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-03-27**:
it worked with the `collide_without_contact` tag, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We did something very similar to this with the [MudPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/de20d7921de62b5decbe2900523e75dc2e36da1d/plugins/MudPlugin.cc?at=default) (added in [pull request 448](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/448/mud-plugin/diff)). It uses a special sdf tag called `collide_without_contact`, though it only works in ODE right now. Take a look at that.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-03-27**:
worked like a charm, thanks :)