# Detect overlapping meshes without physical simulation in gazebo-harmonic

Tags: gazebo

**Task description:**
I want to add custom meshes programmatically to my world and detect if it's interfering/overlapping with another mesh. I don't want to simulate the physical behaviour of a potencial collision, I just want to check the geometry of the scene and also get the closest distance between these two meshes.
The purpose is to test a lot of different configurations and see which configurations aren't geometrically possible and see the distances of the non interfering meshes.

**What I tried so far:**
I tried to detect a potential collision with the TouchPlugin and this is working initially with the first pose. But for example if my meshes are interfering at the first pose, I can not simply reorientate one of my meshes, because it would be stuck inside the other mesh, while gazebo would still try to calculate it's physical behaviour, causing the simulation to (nearly) collapse.

Of course gazebo is made for simulating the physical behaviour, but it's also solving the calculation of interfering meshes as a part of the problem and I wonder, if it's somehow possible to use gazebo just for solving for geometrically calculations.

I already found an [related issue on stackexchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/detecting-collisions-without-very-small-interfering-with-physical-objects), but it's outdated with dead links and related to gazebo classic.

Has anyone an idea how to restrict the behaviour of gazebo or already solved a related issue like this?

Comment: I have seen and tested the attribute ```collide_without_contact```, but it doesn't has any observable effect on my simulation:  
<surface>  
 <bounce>  
  <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>  
 </bounce>  
 <contact>  
  <collide_without_contact>true</collide_without_contact>  
 </contact>  
</surface>